# OpenCV fillConvexPoly function in C++ throws exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to fill a triangle in a mask using the `fillConvexPoly` function.
But I get the following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (points.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0) in fillConvexPoly, file /home/iris/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp, line 2256
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /home/iris/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2256: error: (-215) points.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function fillConvexPoly
```

I call the function as like so,

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(r2.size(), CV_32FC3);
cv::fillConvexPoly(mask, trOutCroppedInt, cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 16, 0);
```

where the trOutCroppedInt defined like so,

```
std::vector<cv::Point> trOutCroppedInt
```

And I push 3 points in the vector,

```
[83, 46; 0, 48; 39, 0]
```

How should I correct this error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This works flawlessly for me, probably you have some problem in the code you're not showing

Answer (score 4):

**When points.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0) is encountered**

This error may occur when the data type is more complex than CV_32S and the dimension is greater than two, for example all data type like `vector<Point2f>` can create the problem. As the result we can use `fillConvexpoly` according to the following steps:

**1. Reading an Image with**

```
cv::Mat src=cv::imread("what/ever/directory");
```

**2. determine points**
You must determine your points like in the following graphic

[image]

Thus, our code for this point is:

```
vector<cv::Point> point;
point.push_back(Point(163,146));  //point1
point.push_back(Point(100,148));  //point2
point.push_back(Point(100,110));  //point3
point.push_back(Point(139,110));  //point4
```

**3.Use `cv::fillConvexPoly` function**

Consider the image `src` and draw a polygon ((with the points)) on this image then code would be as follows:

```
   cv::fillConvexPoly(src,               //Image to be drawn on
                      point,             //C-Style array of points
                      Scalar(255, 0, 0), //Color , BGR form
                      CV_AA,             // connectedness, 4 or 8
                      0);                // Bits of radius to treat as fraction
```

(so output image is as follows: before:left side - after:right side)

[image]